# Navigate to Template using angular route

Tags: angularjs, cordova, angular-route-segment

I have been trying to navigate to views using angulateJs ngRoute. 
I defined first navigation using

```
$routeProvider.
            when('/login', {
                templateUrl: 'login.html',
                controller: 'loginCtrl'

            }).
            when('/home', {
                templateUrl: 'home.html'
            }).
            otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/login'
            });
```

Now I want to move to page home from loginController. How can I achieve that. every post just saying about navigating from main page only. 
I tried with

```
app.controller('loginCtrl', function($scope, $location){
    $scope.login = function(){
        $location.path('/home');
    }
});
```

Comment: app.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, $location){
    $scope.login = function(){
        $location.path('/home');
    }
});

Its not working

Answer (score 1):

Binod you should probably look in to the $state injector on the controller. This `$state` will have states to which you can reach, which are internally mapped to some other templates, like `$state.go('someOtherPage')`.
I would suggest you to checkout `$stateProvider`

Comment: With state provider is better or route provider

Comment: added the solution with state provider

Answer (score 0):

Inject `$location` in your code where u want to go to the template, and then use `$location.path('/home');`

Comment: how to inject location

Answer (score 0):

try

```
       when('/home',{
                templateUrl : 'home.html',
                controller : 'HomeController'
       })
```

and create one empty controller with the name HomeController.

Comment: my Problem is I want to navigate to /home from login controller

Comment: Just check the location of home.html in the folder structure of your project.

Answer (score 0):

Solved using $stateProvider.

```
var routerApp = angular.module('starter', ['ui.router','']);
```

routerApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');

$stateProvider

    .state('login', {
        url: '/login',
        templateUrl: 'login.html',
        controller: 'loginCtrl'
    })

    .state('home', {
        url: '/homeffgfg',
        templateUrl: 'home.html'  
    });
```

});

and Login Controller is

```
app.controller('loginCtrl', function($scope, $state){
$scope.login = function(){
    $state.go('home');
}
```

});

ui.router dependency is important and `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular-ui-router.js"></script>`